# Change color of all active links javascript CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have several buttons on a page which change color from blue to red when pressed down. I want a reset button to reset the colors of the buttons to blue without having to reload the entire page. Is this possible?

```
<button id="btn" onClick="style.backgroundColor='red'; style.border='3px solid red'; style.color='#FFF';">Copy</button>
```

Comment: You could assign a class of `.red` to them instead of setting the style with javascript. On press down, add the class, and when you click reset button it removes the class.

Comment: @Amberlamps - it's the inline version of the DOM level zero click event.

Comment: you can do on press down. Why not create some CSS? `#btn:active{background-color: red; border: 3px solid red;color:#FFF;}`

Answer (score 2):

this will help http://jsfiddle.net/3hqnU/ simple use of jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
onmouseup="this.style.backgroundColor='blue'"
```

but like Andy said, you should use CSS classes, switching between them, for this kind of styles

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with HTML+CSS+JS

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/yK653/